# Access a column from a Flask-SQLAlchemy paginate result

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My `Document` model has a `text_location` column, a file path that I need to read from after querying. I am using `paginate` when querying.

That is created through this code:

```
class Document(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text_location = db.Column(db.String)

page_views = Document.query.paginate(page, 1, False)
```

I can display `{{ page_views }}` correctly in the template. However, if I try to open `text_location`, I get `"Pagination" object has no attribute "text_location"`.

```
with open(page_views.text_location) as f:
    document_text = f.read()
```

How can I read the `text_location` for the `Documents` I queried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy's [`paginate`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.paginate) method returns a [`Pagination`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination) object. The list of items retrieved is in the [`items`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination.items) attribute. Iterate over `items` to get individual model results.

```
pager = Document.query.paginate()

for document in pager.items:
    with open(document.text_location) as f:
        document.text = f.read()
```