# How to update values when using Pagination?

Tags: flask, pagination, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How to increment the `views` value each time a post is retrieved using the `Pagination` object? For example, the below code results in `TypeError: 'Pagination' object is not iterable`:

```
@app.route('/myview/<int:page>')
def view(page=1):
    per_page = 10
    posts = Posts.query.order_by(Posts.time.desc()).paginate(page, per_page, error_out=False)
    for post in posts:
        post.views += 1
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('view.html',posts=posts)
```

Comment: @Gerg can you please check without pagination(using .all()) what result you are getting

Comment: @MohammadAarif It works fine with `.all()`

Comment: @Greg, what is `views` in your case, a feature in the `Post` model? Or are you trying to update the result of the pagination itself?

Comment: @calestini views is an integer column in the `Post` table. Not trying to update the result of the pagination object, only trying to record that the object/row has been retrieved/read from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand there are two things happening:

1. Pagination of object Posts
2. Saving a new information on each row that is retrieved

**Part 1**: Pagination is a class returned by `paginate` and the way to iterate through the elements is via `items`. That is why you are getting a `TypeError` when trying to iterate through the `Pagination` class. You can see more on the [docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination), or on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413062/access-a-column-from-a-flask-sqlalchemy-paginate-result)

The correct way to iterate would be:

```py
for post in posts.items:
    # your code
```

**Part 2**: If you want to update the object as you iterate though it, you would also need to add it and commit. I am not sure the object can actually be updated as you are looping, but you could try:

```py
session = db.session

for post in posts.items:
    post.views += 1
    session.add(post)

session.commit()
return render_template('view.html',posts=posts)
```

If it does not work you can either append the ids to a list and update all at the end, or query and update inside the loop, using a different session.

```py
posts_rendered = []
for post in posts.items:
    posts_rendered.append(post.id)

session.query(Posts).filter(Posts.id.in_(posts_rendered))\
    .update({Posts.views: Posts.views + 1})
session.commit()
```

A great response on updates can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270879/efficiently-updating-database-using-sqlalchemy-orm)

Answer (score 0):

you can not iterate [directly](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination) paginate object-

you have to iterate on items -

```
for post in posts.itmes:
```